# Adding a unique column to existing sql database

Tags: sql, unique, addition, firebird

I want to add a column to an existing Firebird database (version 2.5) and write a procedure by which I can assign each record a different value. Something like add a column and autogenerate the data for it.

Like, if I add a new column called "ID" (number) I want then initialize a unique value to each of the records. So, my ID column will have records from say 1 to 500. How can I achieve this by using only sql script (i.e. without using some high-level programming language for generating sql commands)?

Basically what I need is something like [identity](http://www.firebirdnews.org/?p=4030) columns in Firebird 3.0:

```
alter table MY_TABLE
add ID int identity(1,1)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This columns will have a default value of 1:

```
alter table MY_TABLE add ID int default 1
```

You can have an auto-incrementing PK using a generator and a BEFORE INSERT trigger:

```
CREATE GENERATOR GEN_PK;
COMMIT;


CREATE TRIGGER GENERATE_PK FOR MY_TABLE
ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT
AS
BEGIN
  IF(NEW.ID IS NULL) THEN 
    NEW.ID = GEN_ID(GEN_PK, 1);
END
```

I didn't understand when you need the random data you said, though.

note that they are two different examples, they are not to be used on together on the same column

Comment: Maybe I was not enough precise when formulating my question. I don't need random data in new column. Just regular auto-incremented value beginning from 1 (or 0, or 10 it doesn't matter). Problem is, I need add new column to already populated table. Are you sure trigger will triggered for existing records?

Comment: No, trigger wont update existing records, you have to issue an update statement for that: `UPDATE MY_TABLE SET ID = GEN_ID(GEN_PK, 1)`

Answer (score 1):

This statement will help you:

```
EXECUTE BLOCK
AS
  DECLARE VARIABLE DBKEY CHAR(8);
  DECLARE VARIABLE C INTEGER = 1;
BEGIN
  FOR 
    SELECT 
      RDB$DB_KEY 
    FROM 
      your_table_name 
    INTO 
      :dbkey
  DO BEGIN
    UPDATE your_table_name SET id = :c WHERE rdb$db_key = :dbkey;
    c = :c + 1;
  END
END
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to add another answer because I cant write @id more than one time on a comment

No, trigger wont fire for existing columns. You can use @ain solutions or  do something like this before create the trigger:

```
DECLARE @id INT 
SET @id = 0 
UPDATE MY_TABLE
SET @id = id = @id + 1 
GO
```